# Controlling Game Flow in unity using Game Manager

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using unity for game development. I am trying to control movement of park barrier. My concept is like I have placed two cubes. One in front of barrier and second one behind barrier. When my car enters on first cube OnTriggerEnter function is called and I move my barrier upward. After that I move my car to second barrier. When my car enters in second barrier OnTriggerEnter function is called. my cube move downward. But when it reaches downward it starts to vibrate.
Maybe it's because Update function on both scripts is being called simultaneously.
My question is how can I use GameManager to have One method for moving barrier up and down. My code is below.

This is for second Cube.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MovingTerrain2 : MonoBehaviour {
    MovingTerrain mov = new MovingTerrain();
    private bool down = false;
    public GameObject barrier;
    private Vector3 movement;
    private int speed = -2;
    void Start()
    {
        movement = new Vector3(0, 1f, 0);
    }
    void Update() 
    {
        if (down == true)
        {
            if (barrier.transform.position.y >= 1)
                barrier.transform.Translate(movement * Time.deltaTime*speed);

        }
    }
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col) 
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Player") 
        {
            down = true;
            mov.top = false;
        }
    }
}
```

This is for First Cube.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MovingTerrain : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject barrier;
    private Vector3 movement;
    public bool top = false;
    void Start() 
    {
        movement = new Vector3(0, 1f, 0);
    }
    void Update() 
    {
        if (top == true) 
        {
            if(barrier.transform.position.y<=4)
            barrier.transform.Translate(movement*Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Player") 
        {
            top = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: for things like this, use coroutines, not update. also except for a different direction (hint, hint) your two scripts are pretty much the same, make it one. https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/intermediate/scripting/coroutines

Comment: How can I make it one script?

Comment: well you only need a way to tell direction to the script. this could be as simple as a bool (up/down), an enum for readability, or a Vector3 for most control. but thinking about it again, you may even consider to teach your door what it means to open and close (a function) and use the triggers to call it. that would be 2 scripts then though. maybe i find some time to write you a full answer later this day.